# How to I use string in formula?

Tags: excel, vba

In this code cell is giving me "#NAME?" error. Here I want to sum the cell from the "E11" to the end of the column.

```
Dim row As String
Dim col1 As String
Dim lc As String

row = Evaluate("=SUM(LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""""),ROW(A:A))+1)")
col1 = "E"
lc = col1 & row

Range(lc).Formula = "=SUM(E11:lc)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Range(lc).Formula = "=SUM(E11:" & lc & ")"`

Comment: You are going to end up with a circular reference as your formula will refer to the cell that it is in.

Comment: If I print the value of "lc" in another cell (For eg. H5) and then I use =SUM(E11:INDIRECT(H5)) then it will do the sum correctly.